Is iot service sdk for Java https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-service-sdk-java maintained?
I could see set of issues raised in https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-service-sdk-java, but there seems to be no action taken. Any idea if the repository for IoT service SDK for java is still maintained?
There is no person whom shown as responsible for the repository , no ownership or so.... what is the status of the repository and what is the future plan for the repository? OK, looks like I need to add 220 characters to ask a question, but do not have anything else to say.
repository is still maintained?

Please share more details about the issue you are facing with the code. Please provide the code in text format and describe the issue in text format

@Sampath, isn't the question has link to the repository where the list of issues are listed which are not yet responded? what else you want?
